# How To create a shortcut for a command in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and was wondering if their was a way to shortcut a line of code.
For example could I use something along the lines of.

```
command = input()
if command = "create turtle"
    t =turtle.Pen()
```

or

```
turtleCommand = input()
if turtleCommand = "circle"
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(91)
```

The turtle thing is just hypothetical maybe if a string "inputted" (if thats a word) activated a defineFunction

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you want something you can use repeatedly, just write a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function:

```
def draw_circle(t):
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(91)
```

And then call it:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
command = input()

if command == "circle":
    draw_circle(t)
elif command = "stuff":
    ...
```

A more robust solution would be to use a dictionary that maps commands to functions:

```
commands = {
    "circle": draw_circle,
    "square": draw_square
}
```

And then get a function by name:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
turtle_command = input()
command = commands[turtle_command]

command(t)
```

Comment: thanks a heap that makes sense. I hate how when i ask questions here a wind up looking like an idiot at the simple answer. I was trying to mold by code around the input()  function

Comment: @user2239009 There aren't stupid questions. Despite what people may want you to believe, we all started asking the same question as you. *I want to do a thing again, but dont want to copy it, how can I do that?*

Answer (score 1):

```
def docircle(pen):
  pen.forward(100)
  pen.left(91)

commands = {
  'circle': docircle,
   ...
}

...

commands[turtleCommand](t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a dictionary mapping a word to the function you want the word to activate:

```
commands = {'create turtle': create_turtle,
            'circle': circle, }

def create_turtle():
    t = turtle.Pen()

def draw_circle():
    ...
```

And then:

```
command = input()
commands[command]()
```